# Why is this perl regex not doing DOTALL correctly?

Tags: regex, perl

I am using perl regex operations from the command line to modify a file (in linux), and want to know why it is failing to modify the file.  Here is the regex:

```
perl -i -pe 'undef $/; s#(<web-app[^>]*>).*?(</web-app>)#\1CHEESE\n\2#gsi' filePath/web.xml
```

Now, this SHOULD be correctly matching multiline blocks. But, it isn't.  Sample input:

```
<web-app xmlns= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
<stuff goes here and tags and things>
</web-app>
```

However nothing is changed.  Dotall should be matching, and this works in an online regex testing tool,but fails with Perl.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: DO not parse multiline blocks of XML with regex.  Use an XML paring module. you'll be glad that you did.

Comment: Len Jaffe: If I were only doing XML, I'd agree.  But, you don't have the full context: this is part of a larger project that operates on a variety of different file types, and uses both shellscript and perl depending on need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to read whole file at once and make a substitution, and `-0777` parameter does exactly that.

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's#(<web-app[^>]*>).*?(</web-app>)#\1CHEESE\n\2#gsi' filePath/web.xml
```

previously `$/` was set when first line was already read so regex couldn't match on partial content.

Comment: the `-0` sets the `$/` (ifs) to zero. If you want ensure slurp the whole file, use number above 0400 (by convention usually uses the `-0777`)

Comment: `-0` sets it to `$/ = "\000";` which can be considered safe for text file?

Comment: yes, can considered to safe for text files, but you stated: _You want to read whole file at once and make a substitution, and -0 parameter does exactly that._ - and this is not fully correct... right? :) ;)

Comment: Good answer, this resolves the issue.  Accepted because more elegant than the BEGIN one.

Comment: +1, but you have a crimson typo `when first line was already red` :)

Comment: @zx81 crimson indeed, tnx for catching it. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `-p` option, the script is inside the body of a `while (<>)` loop. So `undef $/;` won't be executed until after you get into the loop. So the first iteration will process the first line of input, and the second iteration will process the rest of the input.

You can insert code before the loop using a `BEGIN` block:

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN {undef $/;} s#(<web-app[^>]*>).*?(</web-app>)#\1CHEESE\n\2#gsi' filePath/web.xml
```